# How to generate a pack of size_t from 0 to N in C++ where N is known at compile time

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

Background: I have a function that I wrote that takes some callable object and a tuple, and unpacks the tuple into the a parameter pack that can be passed to the function.  You can probably imagine that this involves a bit of template recursion.  However, most of my colleagues aren't native speakers of C++, so they understandably have trouble with the code, as well as the compilation errors they get when the function is called incorrectly.

If I could just generate a pack of size_t from 0 to the size of the tuple - 1, I could use the following one-liner:

```
template <class Function, class... TupleArgs>
auto UnpackTuple(Function fn, std::tuple<TupleArgs>&& t)
-> decltype(fn(std::declval<TupleArgs>()...)) {
  return fn(std::get<{my size_t pack}>(std::forward(t))...);
}
```

Is there anything I can substitute for "my size_t pack" to make this work?  I know I could hack something together if I new that each type in TupleArgs was unique, but that's a very specific case that isn't useful to me.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence

Comment: If you insist on writing it manually, add another parameter pack `size_t ...I` and a dummy parameter of type `std::index_sequence<I...>`, then pass `std::make_index_sequence<N>{}` into that new parameter.

Comment: My workplace is still on C++ 14 :(  (Regarding the std::apply comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for [`std::apply`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply), which will do exactly what you want to do with `UnpackTuple`.

That being said, if you need to do this manually for some odd reason (*you probably shouldn't, unless you want to do something entirely different from calling a function*), 
[`std::make_index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) does *almost* what you want (except that your `size_t` sequence is wrapped in a type, so you need an additional level of indirection). You can see how it is used in the example implementation of `std::apply` at cppreference.com:<sup>1)</sup>

```
template <class F, class Tuple, std::size_t... I>
constexpr decltype(auto) apply_impl(F&& f, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
}

template <class F, class Tuple>
constexpr decltype(auto) apply(F&& f, Tuple&& t)
{
    return apply_impl(
        std::forward<F>(f),
        std::forward<Tuple>(t),
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>>{}
    );
}
```

Since you mentioned that you are still on C++14, you'll need to replace `std::invoke` with a normal function call (keep the `std::forward`, however, in case someone is mad enough to implement a `operator() &&`)

<sup><sup>1)</sup> (CC-BY-SA 3.0)</sup>

Comment: That's pretty cool - I was so fixated on trying to find a way to produce the index pack, I hadn't even considered making the function *infer* the pack.